# Unable to handle repository shortcut 'universe'

Tags: linux, kali-linux, repository, universe

Just installed kali linux being new to this linux world after installing i followed this article from fossmint about the [first 10things to do after installing kali linux](https://www.fossmint.com/things-to-do-after-installing-kali-linux/) but on the 8th step while installing the katoolin applicaiton i got some error so i searched for the article which showed step by step installation of katoolin i ended up on this [article](https://distroid.net/install-use-katoolin-linux/) it says we should have some programs which is python python3 which are there in my kali linux but it also needed a universe repository , so i searched for the command to install universe repository to kali linux

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

after running this command it showed me this error

> Unable to handle repository shortcut 'universe'

How do i fix this ?
my system
OS: Kali Linux (recently installed)

Edit: Thank you for your help as a newbie in the Linux world. I was advised on what to do and what not to do in Kali Linux. I learned that the universe and multiverse repositories are not available for Debian-based OS and that Kali Linux is not recommended for beginners. Going forward, I will only follow Kali Official documentation and avoid relying on random articles if I continue to use Kali Linux.

Comment: The main article you posted is from 2019.  Kali is now 2023. What version are you using (I am using V2023)?   It may be that some tweaks then have been superseded now.

Comment: Katoolin is a tool to install "all Kali tools". There are 600+ of them - NOBODY needs or uses them all. You can't have "universe" available because Kali doesn't have that repo. Don't follow random articles, follow [Kali documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs). Kali is _very_ [not recommended](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/) for newbies or as a desktop distro. Install one for desktop use, and run Kali as a [Virtual Machine](https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-virtual-machines). Use Debian (or -based) desktop distro to learn skills for Kali maintenance.

Comment: As a matter of fact "universe" and "multiverse" aren't available for Debian at all. They seem to be specific to Ubuntu and maybe its derivatives. And _"adding other operating system’s repositories into Kali (such as trying to put Ubuntu on Kali), will break your installation. This is the single most common reason why Kali Linux systems break"_ as the developers [advise](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/).